# Grails many to many join table

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, many-to-many, grails-orm

I need to model a relationship between Person and Interest
A person can have many interests. The interests are independent of the people who refer them (there could be many people with the same interest).

```
class People {
    String name
    static hasMany = [interests:Interes]

    static constraints = {}

class Interes {
    String name
    static hasMany = [People]
    static constraints = {}
```

The problem: Hibernate automatically creates the people_interest table but there is no way to load the data into it.

I tried on Bootstrap.groovy

```
def p1 = new Person(name: "John").addToInterests.(new Interest(name:"Music")).save()
```

Some considerations:
I created the application using
grails create-app backend --profile rest-api. And for the rest grails generate-all rest.Person

I enclose the self-generated code

```
import grails.validation.ValidationException
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CREATED
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY

import grails.gorm.transactions.ReadOnly
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

@ReadOnly
class InteresController {

    InteresService interesService

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond interesService.list(params), model:[interesCount: interesService.count()]
    }

    def show(Long id) {
        respond interesService.get(id)
    }

    @Transactional
    def save(Interes interes) {
        if (interes == null) {
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }
        if (interes.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond interes.errors
            return
        }

        try {
            interesService.save(interes)
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            respond interes.errors
            return
        }

        respond interes, [status: CREATED, view:"show"]
    }

    @Transactional
    def update(Interes interes) {
        if (interes == null) {
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }
        if (interes.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond interes.errors
            return
        }

        try {
            interesService.save(interes)
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            respond interes.errors
            return
        }

        respond interes, [status: OK, view:"show"]
    }

    @Transactional
    def delete(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            render status: NOT_FOUND
            return
        }

        interesService.delete(id)

        render status: NO_CONTENT
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, try to add save(failOnError:true) and see possible error

Comment: I tried and there are no errors. The problem is that the content is not saved in the intermediate table (people_interest)